# Обратимые операции с числами

Tags: операторы

Здравствуйте! Есть к примеру такие числа: "42, 58, 231, 195, 100, 95". Если ли в математики какие-то формулы, которые позволяет соединить все числа в одно с возможностью восстановления их из результата? Банальный пример 42+58=100 -> 100=42+58. Результат должен быть меньше чем если просто добавить одно число к другому.

Comment: 100 = 50+50, подумайте над этим...

Comment: 7 - это сумма двух чисел 1+6, 2+5, 3+4... Возможно, имеет значение и расположение: 4+3, 5+2, 6+1. А есть еще дробные числа. Суммируются 3, 4 и более чисел. И не только суммируются. И чем больше разрядов, тем больше вариантов...===/ По Вашей формулировке непонятно, что хотите получить

Comment: По моему уже во втором классе начальной школы сейчас уже рассказывают, что-то про число неизвестных и число у уравнений.

Comment: Вам нужно сжать данные? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Answer (score 0):

Сложение чисел - это своего рода [хеш-функция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), т. е. это необратимый процесс ***(f(x)=y)***. Это означает, что провести обратный процесс невозможно. ***Но*** зато можно пойти на хитрость и превратить эту "хеш-функцию" в "хеш-функцию ***c лазейкой***". Это означает, что можно создать дополнительную переменную, благодаря которой можно провести обратное действие.

Пример №1: x + y = 5 - ***необратимая функция***, так как мы не можем восстановить x и y. 
Пример №2: 3 + y = 5 - ***эта функция обратима***, так как мы знаем, что ***x = 3***. Следовательно, ***y = 5 - 3***. 
Пример №3: 3 + z + w = 7 - ***необратимая функция***, так как мы не можем восстановить z и w. Здесь сразу два неизвестных параметра. 
Пример функции с лазейкой: У нас есть два числа, ***x*** и ***z***, их сумма даёт нам число ***y***. У нас также есть переменная - лазейка ***j***. В неё мы можем записать какую - либо информацию для последующего обратного процесса. Мы можем в неё записать ***x - y***. Тогда при обратном процессе у нас будет две информации:
 - ***x + z = y***
 - ***x - z = j***
Это, как можно заметить, система уравнений. Используя метод алгебраического сложения мы можем получить наипростейшее уравнение "***2x = y+j***". Так как мы знаем и ***y***, и ***j***, мы можем узнать значение ***x***, а зная значение ***x*** мы можем узнать значение ***z***, которое равно "***y-x***". Это всего лишь пример, вы можете записать в ***j*** что угодно, хоть "***j=x/z***", и, опираясь на это узнать ***x*** и ***z***.

Конечно, для того, чтобы сделать обратный процесс нужна сама по себе ***лазейка***, переменная, с помощью которой можно будет очень легко получить входные данные, но другого способа просто ***не существует***.

Answer (score 0):

> Если ли в математики какие-то формулы, которые позволяет соединить все числа в одно с возможностью восстановления их из результата? ... Результат должен быть меньше чем если просто добавить одно число к другому.

Аксиоматично, что общее количество вариантов входной последовательности должно быть не меньше количества вариантов выходной последовательности. Иначе после установления соответствия (вход-выход) для отдельных значений либо останутся входные данные, не имеющие выходных (чего быть не может, исходя из задания), либо каждое оставшееся входное значение должно соответствовать некоему уже использованному ранее выходному. Т.е. будет существовать выходное значение, которому соответствует более одного входного. И нет никаких данных, позволяющих определить, какое из возможных входных использовано для получения именно этого экземпляра выходного.

Применительно к бинарным данным - речь пойдёт о количестве битов в исходной информации и полученной после обработки. С тексто-числовой, текстовой и прочими типами - считать сложнее, но суть та же.